# How to add authentication to Elastic Transport Client

Tags: java, elasticsearch, elastic-stack, search-guard

How to add authentication to elastic transport client.
Are there any opensource authentication plugins for elastic search.
I tried with readonlyrest and searchguard but both of them did not satisfy my requirement.

Comment: was are your requirements?

Comment: Yes i want to add authentication to transport client

Comment: that of course possible with Search Guard https://floragunn.com/transport-client-authentication-authorization/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To use transport level authentication with Search Guard do:

- Set up a transport client, and configure it to use a client certificate when talking to Elasticsearch
- Configure the Distinguished Name of the certificate as a Search Guard user. This user does not need any login credentials or roles since it is already identified by its certificate
- Send a Basic Authentication header with each request. This header contains the username and password and want to use for this request
- Search Guard will apply all security checks for the provided credentials, as if they would have been provided on the REST level
- This means you can implement access control based on indices and types, and also apply document- and field-level security on the transport level.

See also https://floragunn.com/transport-client-authentication-authorization/

Comment: Thanks for your help i will look on with this.

Comment: Did it help? In my case the elasticsearch server always getting 
`No index-level perm match for User [name=_sg_internal, roles=[]]`
It doesn't recognise the user name if call was made from Java